# flutter running a function from another widget. When i press the button 4, the userAnswer won't change its value

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

> so this is a widget in my main screen. KeypadButton is imported from KeypadButton.dart

```
KeypadButton(
    number: 4,
    userAnswer: _userAnswer,
),
```

> this is keypadbutton.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class KeypadButton extends StatefulWidget {
  KeypadButton({this.number, this.userAnswer});
```

> The this.number is 4 and userAnswer is _userAnswer (they are both from main screen)

```
  final int number;
  String userAnswer;

  @override
  _KeypadButtonState createState() => _KeypadButtonState();
}

class _KeypadButtonState extends State<KeypadButton> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text(
          widget.number.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
        onPressed: () => setState(() {
          widget.userAnswer += widget.number.toString();
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve? Your title is only descriptive of the problem for someone who knows the app you are working on. Without more context it is difficult to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change your props directly inside State Part of your Widget. So Widget can depend on external props and can't change them if you pass a property as a variable.

So one of the approaches is using callback as property for your widget, and call it inside this widget when you want. This callback needs to change the state of your main widget that uses KeypadButton.

Or you can use a controller like in standard TextEdit widget from the Flutter SDK. For example, you can use some model class that will keep some information, in KeypadButton you change this model via API of this model class. And in the main widget, you need to get this info from model class